# How to fill down time tracker if having only start & End MM:SS

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Having Excel where I get required hourly down time with only having start & end date time as per the images required any formula or vba command for calculation.

[image]

Comment: If at 01:00 there is 3:39 minutes down, then why 60 at 02:00 ? surely at 02:00 to 03:00 it was 100% worked ie should show 00:00 ?

Answer (score 0):

Please, notice you are mixing different types of data in your output. Value `03:39` is a time value while `60,0` or `0,0` is decimal. You should consider working all of them in decimal if you are going to make any calculations.

Also, you could play with CF rules to **see** the values as you wish, but real value should be decimals.

Anyways, I managed to do it with this:

[image]

```
=IF(HOUR($A2)>HOUR(C$1);0;IF(HOUR($A2)=HOUR(C$1);TEXT("00:"&MINUTE($A2)&":"&SECOND($A2);"mm:ss");IF(HOUR($B2)>HOUR(C$1);TEXT(60;"0,0");IF(HOUR($B2)=HOUR(C$1);TEXT("00:"&MINUTE($B2)&":"&SECOND($B2);"mm:ss");TEXT(0;"0,0")))))
```

Drag to right and bottom.

Notice I'm forcing the format with the TEXT function, so the output **is not numeric but a text** so you cannot do any calculus with it. That's why you should consider using CF rules

Also, depending on your regional setup, masks like `mm:ss` or `0,0` that I use in the formulas may be different in your PC

Comment: Why results with 60,0 and 59:58 ie two different formats?

Comment: @SolarMike No idea, but in the image OP posted you can see it. I think is a wrong approach mixing values types and formats but I don't know OP's needs

Comment: Thankyou So Much.....!
 Its Great help for me Dear